# Python: how to filter pandas.Series with function without losing index association?

Tags: python, filter, pandas, series

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` on which I'm iterating over the rows. On each row I need to filter out some non valuable values and keep the indexes association. This is where I'm at right now:

```
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    my_values = row["first_interesting_column":]
    # here I need to filter 'my_values' Series based on a function
    # what I'm doin right now is use the built-in python filter function, but what I get back is a list with no indexes anymore
    my_valuable_values = filter(lambda x: x != "-", my_values)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I don't think you need to iterate, just do something like:  `df.applymap(lambda x: str(x).find('-'))` outside of any iteration.  And it's usually a good idea to post some sample data and show exactly what sort of results you are trying to get.

Comment: Btw, I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "losing index association" but note that the rows are series when you iterate like this.  Maybe you mean that "i" does not reflect the dataframe index?  Anyway, shouldn't matter if you just avoid iteration in the first place.

Comment: @JohnE I'm iterating because I'm using it to insert values in a DB coming from an XLS. Dunno if it's the right thing to do. When I say I lose index association I mean that by passing the `pandas.Series` to the built-in `filter` function I get back a python `list`, which doesn't come with the original `pandas.Series` index.

Comment: @JohnE by the way I got the answer elsewhere, which was `my_valuable_values = my_values[my_values != "-"]`.

Answer (score 1):

I was suggested the answer by a guy on IRC. Here it is:

```
w = my_values != "-" # creates a Series with a map of the stuff to be included/exluded
my_valuable_values = my_values[w]
```

... which could also be shortened in ...

```
my_valuable_values = my_values[my_values != "-"]
```

... and, of course, to avoid one more step ...

```
row["first_interesting_column":][row["first_interesting_column":] != "-"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is generally bad practice (and very slow) to iterate over rows. As @JohnE suggested you want to use [applymap](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html).

If I understand your question, I think what you want to do is:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

datastring = StringIO("""\
2009    2010    2011   2012
1       4       -      4
3       -       2      3
4       -       8      7
""")
df = pd.read_table(datastring, sep='\s\s+')
a = df[df.applymap(lambda x: x != '-')].astype(np.float).values
a[~np.isnan(a)]
```